# Swift Apple Pay with Stripe Error 50

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay

I have followed Stripe manual to implement Stripe in iOS project. We have the latest version and everything looks like in examples. Keep getting this error:

> Error Domain=com.stripe.lib Code=50 "Your payment information is formatted improperly. Please make sure you're correctly using the latest version of our iOS library. For more information see https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios."

Code is running in simulator, simulated as iPhone 6s and running latest iOS. Anyone got any clue?

Comment: HII Zassx. I implemented apple pay with stripe integration in ios using swift language. I followed stripe official documents. Whenever user tap apple pay button he will see payment sheet right. But in our case, it doesn't appear and says an error like passbook UI service quit unexpectedly. But it is running fine in MacBook air simulator but not in real iPhone 6plus. I didn't get any solution to this. if you know please give the solution.please help me

Comment: @vijju Hey. Sorry other guys from the team did received this task so I was doing some other work back then. Sorry but can't help you on this one.

Comment: ok. Thank you.if you don't mind can you please ask them about the issue.?

Answer (score 0):

Simlulators Are not a real reflection of a device as the docs says insure the version of the libary is exact up to date. You may have a rogue version that does not match up with there schema.

Comment: Just pointed simulator specs to avoid comments and answers like: Apple Pay runs only on iOS > X, device must be > iPhone 6, etc. Also, I have the latest version of stripe, just checked again.